# What was Grandpa's itinerary?

Tags: riddle, pattern, knowledge

Grandpa decides to take a multi-country tour visiting big cities

> First he goes to LIBYA
>
> Then to PERU
>
> Then to BAHRAIN
>
> Then to _______
>
> Then to _______
>
> Then to _______

Fill in the three blanks and tell me why

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe Grandpa's complete itinerary is:

> LIBYA, PERU, BAHRAIN, **MARSHALL ISLANDS**, **ITALY**, **MEXICO**.

**Explanation:** As @El-Guest found, Grandpa is:

> Visiting capital cities where the last two letters of one city are the first two letters of the next: Tripo[**LI**] - [**LI**][*MA*] -- [*MA*]na[**MA**] (the capitals of Libya, Peru and Bahrain respectively).

There are several possibilities for the 4th, 5th and 6th cities on the list if this is the only stipulation. However:

> If - since there are specifically **6 cities** on the list - Grandpa is visiting *one city on each of the 6 civilised/inhabited continents* then there is a unique solution...

Since Grandpa has already visited the 3 cities mentioned just now...

> This removes all country/city combos in Africa (where Libya is), South America (Peru) and Asia (Bahrain). We now need to identify 3 cities where one each is from Europe, North America and Oceania.

There are only 3 such cities which fill the 4th slot on the list:

> [**MA**]dr[*ID*] (Spain, Europe) - but no capitals begin with *ID* so this would end the chain;
>  [**MA**]nag[*UA*] (Nicaragua, North America) - but no capitals begin with *UA* so this does not work either;
>  [**MA**]ju[*RO*] (Marshall Islands, Oceania) - now we're getting somewhere...!

Following this, Grandpa can only go on to visit:

> [*RO*][**ME**] in Italy (Europe) and then end his trip in the North American capital of [**ME**]xico City (in... er... Mexico!). The chain would also naturally end here regardless of the one-per-continent restriction since no capitals begin with TY, so it all fits rather snugly together!

Comment: Great puzzle solving @Stiv

Comment: Stiv - it's wonderful to see the number of previously unsolved puzzles you have managed to complete.

Comment: Thanks @Tom - I've made it a bit of a personal mission :)

Answer (score 7):

He can go to

> MOZAMBIQUE, then CANADA, then JAPAN.

Note the large cities are

> TripoLI, LIMA, MAnaMA, MApuTO, TOronTO, and TOkyo.

Note:

> It doesn’t say capital cities so Toronto counts, it’s the capital of Ontario at any rate.

As M Oehm correctly notes, he could also go to

> The Philippines, Nigeria, and Norway, because of MAniLA, LAgOS, and OSlo.

For only

> capital cities, he can go to EQUATORIAL GUINEA, COLOMBIA, and UZBEKISTAN, because of MAlaBO, BOgoTA, and TAshkent.

Comment: With the same reasoning, he could go to the Philippines, Nigeria and Norway.

Comment: I know, that’s probably a better answer but I don’t think it’s unique.

Comment: I don't claim it's better. It has the same qualification as yours.

Comment: Fair enough. I’ve got another try with all CCs, but one is not big.

Comment: @El-Guest  You are missing a subtle clue in the countries